# How to show the sub-menu on the right side of parent menu using Bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Razor View , want to show the sub menu on the right side of the `parent` item, but currently it is being displayed under the `parent` item! I have applied different `bootstrap classes` but it makes no difference !

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a >Menues</a></li>
    @{
        if (Model.MenuRights != null)
        {
            foreach (MenuRight header in Model.MenuHeaders.ToList())
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Main Item </a><hr />
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
                        <li><a>Inner item 1</a></li> 
                        <li><a>Inner item 2</a></li> 
                        <li><a>Inner item 3</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </li>

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: When posting, please include code that reproduces your issue.  Since we don't know what `Model.MenuHeaders.ToList()` resolved to, it's tough to know what you are aksing.  **Also**, what element are you referring to as the `parent`? Menues?  Or Main item?  Perhaps draw out your desired results.

Comment: Main Item is parent and Inner item* are sub menus! I want to show that sub menus on right side of Main Item! @Mark

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

Created class:

```
.rightMenu {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

And markup becomes:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu  rightMenu" role="menu">
    <hr />
    <li><a>Inner item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Inner item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Inner item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CX8AzuSdBiKEdZDNci77?p=preview).